# Java return index if value found in array

Tags: java, arrays, search

I am trying to find a value in an array and I know for sure that this value will exist only once, so i am trying to find the value and return the index of the array where it is stored, if not found return -1
This is what I am trying to do:

```
static Integer[] accs = new Integer[20];
 public static int search()
    {
        Integer[] numbers;
        numbers = accs;
        Integer key;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter the Account Number:");        
         key = sc.nextInt();

        for (Integer index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++)
      {
           if ( numbers[index] == key )
                 return index;  //We found it!!!
      }
     // If we get to the end of the loop, a value has not yet
     // been returned.  We did not find the key in this array.
     return -1;

    }
```

When I run this even though I know that the value exists in the array, nothing is being displayed. I debugged and then I found out that the Key variable is not having the value of what I typed. Is something wrong there?

Comment: Is there any reason you are using `Integer` rather than `int` ? What do you see in `key` and what were you expecting?

Comment: You're using == for object comparison (which does reference comparison). You should use equals, or simple int. This code will only accidentally work when your numbers are in the Integer cache range

Comment: Use equals instead of == to compare integers. Or use int instead.

Comment: you are comparing Integer objects by reference. You need to use equals

Comment: This code is working what is the wrong in here????

Comment: @mssb really it is working? cause ok my static Integer[] accs = new Integer[20];
is populated from another method as it is a class variable, so when i ask user enter the number he wants to search then i debug and see what is the key value it is showing random number but not my number.. that is y i mentioned it is not working

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes there is static Integer[] accs = new Integer[20];
 is a class variable and so this is used some other place as well and i am using this there... accs.length, which i dont think is applicable for int correct?

Comment: You can do `int[] accs = new int[20]; int len = accs.length;` If you use `int` youc an use `==` instead of having to use `.equals()` i.e. it would solve most of your problems and be more efficient (and shorter)

Comment: @PeterLawrey let me give it a try

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your array is storing Integer, which is a java Object, to test for equality of Java Object you need to call [Object.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method instead of `==`.

In your case I suggest you use an array of `int` instead of `Integer`, it is lighter in memory, support `==` and you are not using any of the features of `Integer` so you don't need them here.

Answer (score 4):

You are checking for *identity* when checking with `operator==` (Are the two references point to the exact same object?) and not *equality* (do they equal each other?).

You should use `int`s (rather then `Integer`s) or change the condition to use the [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

Answer (score 2):

Integer is an object, so you have to make use of the equals method.  Try numbers[index].equals(key).

Answer (score 1):

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(accs).indexOf(key)
```

or

```
org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils.indexOf(accs, key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you understand the difference between object equality and object identity. You are using "==" to check if your value is in the array - this checks for identity, not for equality. Use `numbers[index].equals(key)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need set value for each element before search.
The statement below only declare new array with 20 element with value = null
static Integer[] accs = new Integer[20];
Replace by:
static Integer[] accs = new Integer[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
and retest.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

initialize the array like this way `static Integer[] accs = {3,5,15,6,4,32,9};` and call  `search()` method in the main. your function work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use following command for capture user input
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));